# __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments 1 given in airflow dag task

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG like

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import date time
dag_crawl = DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag',
    start_date= datetime(year=2017, month=3, day=28),)
```

and task like

```
test_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'test_task',
    python_callable = AClass().a_method,
    # to pass self as first argument while calling a_method
    op_args = [AClass()],
)
```

inspite of passing self while calling the method 'a_method' of the class 'AClass()'

I am getting **Broken DAG: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)**.

Can you give some advice to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to pass *self* object while calling a method: a_method of the class:AClass() when you refer to the method to be called in callable `python_callable = AClass().a_method` is enough without self. You don't have to pass op_args with [AClass()]. This error: **Broken DAG: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)** is because your AClass() expects an argument that you did not give (my most likely guess).

You need something like

```
test_task = PythonOperator(
task_id = 'test_task',
python_callable = AClass(some_param=some_value).a_method,
)
```

Comment: that was stupid of me to pass self. This reason was exactly what you said, thanks.